# Node.JS Web Application Create MongooseDB Connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a connection to MongoDB from a Node.JS application but I can't get the connection working. I just get errors saying:

> TypeError: mongoose.createConnection is not a function

Same for just mongoose.connection also..

I just have a serivce class and I'm trying to create a connecting inside of it:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export class MongoDbService{
constructor(){
    db = mongoose.createConnection(url)
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'))
        .once('open', function callback() {
            console.log('db connection open');
        });

    console.log(db);
}
```

Surely this is possible ???

I'm trying to build a web application that talks to mongodb, nothing fancy at all.. Mongoose v5.1.6 is install also.

Comment: Did you try `mongoose.connect(url)`?

Comment: In my ignorance I assumed I could use this to connect to the MongDB cloud service from a client, but this obviously doesn't work